# android studio clock set time only show 0 or 30

Tags: java, android

I use android write to set time,
I use edittext, when I click ,it will show clock TimePickerDialog,
how can I only show 0 and 30 on my clock? but I have some limit
I hope my hour just can set AM8-17,and minute just can set 00 or 30
EX:8:30 / 14:00.....
I don't know how to do it, can someone help me? thanks.
this is my code,

```
    time2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(hasFocus){
                showtime2();
            }
        }
    });
 private void showtime2() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    new TimePickerDialog(Off.this, R.style.DatePickBackgroundColor2, new 
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            String tmp="",tmp2="";
            if(hourOfDay<10){tmp="0"+hourOfDay;}else tmp=""+hourOfDay;
            if(minute<10){tmp2="0"+minute;}else tmp2=""+minute;
            time2.setText(tmp + ":" + tmp2);
        }
    },  c.get(Calendar.HOUR), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false).show();
}
```

[image: This is my clock picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say you have a time picker in your xml file like the one below, pay attention to using spinner as the time picker's mode so that you can show TimePicker with intervals:

```
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timepicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:timePickerMode="spinner"/>
```

Set `setIs24HourView()` to true in order to get rid of am/pm and call a function in which you will set the displayable value.

```
TimePicker timepicker = findViewById(R.id.timepicker);
timepicker.is24HourView();
setInterval(timepicker);
```

Finally, the `setInterval()` function should be like this depending on your need:

```
private void setInterval(TimePicker timePicker) {
        try {

            NumberPicker minutePicker = timePicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(
                    "minute", "id", "android"));

            String[] display = new String[] { "0", "30" };

            minutePicker.setMinValue(0);
            minutePicker.setMaxValue(display.length - 1);
            minutePicker.setDisplayedValues(display);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: hello,but I use edittext, when I click ,it will show clock, how can I only show 0 and 30 on my clock? thanks.